# Auto increment string in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

is there a way to add auto increment to a PK which has both letters and numbers in mysql?

I'd like the letters to stay the same but the number to change. some thing like ad001, ad002,ad003...

thanks for the help

Comment: Does https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72902/auto-increment-value-needs-to-be-set-as-s1 help?

Comment: No, you cannot add 1 to a random text. You'll need to roll your own solution (maybe a calculated column).